# Is there a way around using client_secret.json to authenticate Google API requests?

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api

I wrote a Python script that uses the Google APIs to send an html email to yourself with your upcoming Google Tasks and Calendar events. What I want to do is to make it distributable so that anyone could download it and use it, but as is it requires the user to configure the app in the Google Developers Console and download a client_secrets.json to the path before being able to run it.

You can take a look at the whole script [here](https://github.com/sfirrin/GTasks-Emailer/blob/master/TasksEmailer.py) if you want but the relevant part is this, which I more or less took directly from the Google quickstart page:

```
SCOPES = ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks.readonly  '
          'https://mail.google.com/ '
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly')
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'GTasks Emailer'


def get_credentials():
"""..."""
home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
    os.makedirs(credential_dir)

credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir, 'gtasks-emailer.json')

store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
credentials = store.get()
if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
    flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
    if flags:
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
    else:  # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
        credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
    print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
return credentials
```

I have spent a while searching and looking at the Google OAuth2 pages and trying to figure out how to authenticate in a way that doesn't use client_secrets but it is sort of over my head so I was hoping someone here could shed some light on it for me.

Comment: The client id and client secret is what identifies your particular application at Google. If you want to give this script to other people so they can create their own application from it, they have to get their own client id and client secret (which is the content of the `client_secret.json`-file you mentioned).

Comment: @Tholle ah I see that's what I was trying to avoid. How do devs get around giving out their client_secret files when they distribute applications that use the Google API?

Comment: If you are using a version control system like GIT, you could put the `client_secret.json`-file in your `.gitignore`-file, and give all your colleagues access to the Google Developer Console, and have them download it from there. Or you could keep a copy on a USB device and give it manually to the programmers in your office, or store it in environment variables in a production setting.

Comment: @Tholle Thanks for replying again. I have put `client_secret` in `.gitignore`. I'm not really working with anyone on this project, so I don't really need to give out the code for that reason. I was more thinking along the lines of making it so that a user could download the `.py` from github and be able to run it and use it on their own without needing to bother with setting it up with Google because the application is already registered in my Developer Console.

Comment: Ah, I see :) That is sadly not possible, but I think anyone who downloads it will not see a problem with registering an application and getting a `client_secret.json` for themselves :)

Comment: @Tholle Ah okay thanks for your help (today and yesterday!)